How to configure sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap to use different destinations?
I want to configure sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap to use different destination writers depending on the Level. Is this possible?
Currently all my logs are going to stderr.
I want only errors and critical to go to stderr and rest to stdout.
ctrl.SetLogger(zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&zap.Options{Development: false, Level: zapcore.DebugLevel})))

